# Are paper-input 2.0 value two way bindable with Polymer 2

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements, polymer-2.x, shady-dom

Polymer's paper-input element allows two way binding of value attribute when used with shady DOM. But it does not allow two way binding with Polymer 2 because Polymer 2 uses shadow DOM
`<paper-input label="User Name" value="{{username}}"> </paper-input>`

There is a possible explanation here https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/issues/297 
But I am not sure if I understood it correctly or I am missing something. It is little hard to believe that paper-input was never intended to be two way bindable?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example of your problem. Two-way binding should work without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<paper-input>` works with two way binding. Tested with Polymer 2.

b.t.w. The github issue was closed over a year ago...

Comment: Actually I was working on a project to upgrade from Polymer 1 to Polymer 2, thats where it wasn't working. I also tested in fresh Polymer 2 application and it worked. Thanks